# How can I transform or plot my data to see power consumption more easily?

Tags: mathematics, plotting, transformation

I have two heating tapes installed in my setup and they provide heat to maintain the reaction at a certain setpoint temperature. Basically, the heating tapes go on a cycle of on/off to maintain the temperature range. How can I better plot my data so I can extract the information better?. It looks like a sea of points that don't convey what is expected. I want to see the percentage of power delivered as a function of time.[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can try to bin your x axis variable, decreasing the number of data points. I.e. you don't plot every single observation but rather the mean value of every, say, two minute interval. Example in R:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(data.table)
set.seed(1)
dt <- as.data.table(expand.grid(
  Time = seq(0, 50, by = 0.01),
  `Power Line` = as.factor(c(1, 2))
))

# Make Watts dependent on Time with some added noise
dt[, Watts := (1 - Time / 100) * rexp(n = nrow(df))]

ggplot(dt, aes(x = Time, y = Watts, color = `Power Line`)) +
  geom_point()

dtBinned <- dt[, .(Watts = mean(Watts)), by = .(Time = 2 * round(Time / 2), `Power Line`)]

ggplot(dtBinned, aes(Time, Watts, color = `Power Line`)) +
  geom_point(size = 4) # increase the dot size a little bit so it's easier to see
```

[image: Not binned]
[image: Binned]